# How to interpret W value of a wilcoxon test in R

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I did a wilcoxon test in R but I don't understand how to interpret the W value and what this means in comparison to another

I did result on 2 data sets and the results are:

W = 9, p-value = 0.1 alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

W = 4, p-value = 1 alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

I understand that the results are not significant because of the P value being less than 0.05 but what does a W value of 9 and 4 actually mean and what does this mean in terms of the first data set compared to to the second data set. Also what does "alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0" mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is the signed rank-sum of the test, and its value depends on what test you did (paired or not). Tha larger value of W indicates the larger difference between groups. However it doesn't indicates the P-values since the W needs to be compared to the null distribution.

"true location shift is not equal to 0" indicates that the two distributions have different means.